# Connected components are equal if they are in the continuous image of a connected set.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function. Where $X$ is a connected topological space and $x,y\in f(X)-$connected subspace of $Y$. Then $$C_x=C_y$$

Where $C_x$ is the connected component of $x$, which is the union of all connected sets containing x.

Proof: $x,y\in f(X)$ so $f(X)\subset C_x,C_y$ so $C_x\cap C_y\not=\emptyset$ so $C_x\cup C_y$ is connected and by definition $C_x\cup C_y=C_x, =C_y$ and finish.

Comment: That is a  valid proof.

Comment: $C_x$ would be the connected component of $f(x)$ in $Y$, not the connected component of $x$ itself, which would be the entire space $X$. But that is how you use it and $C_y$ in the proof itself, so the error is only in the definition, not your proof.